# node inside a rectangle with same height as the rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm making a timetable where I draw rectangles with x-coordinates of the day and y-coordinates of the time. Centered inside these rectangles these is a node with some text. Because of several reasons, the fill color cannot be applied to the rectangle but has to be applied to the node itself.
The problem is, that I cannot (or that I don't know how) apply a height to the node, so my fill color only spans around the text, but not around the entire time period of the entry.

How could I make the node as tall as the rectangle?

---

#### Here is some code of my project

```
\newcommand{\entry}[7]{
    \draw
        (#1, {time(#2)}) rectangle (#1+1, {time(#3)}) % {time(#2)} begin of the entry, {time(#3)} end of the entry
        node [
            rectangle split, 
            rectangle split parts=2, 
            pos = .5, 
            fill = #6, 
            text = #7, 
            text width = \entrytextwidth cm, 
            text centered
        ] 
        {\small{\textbf{#4}} \nodepart{second} \footnotesize{#5}};
}
```

Where `time()` is:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{time}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\firstH-(floor(#1)+(#1-floor(#1))/0.6)}%
 }
```

The time is passed as a float in the format `hh.mm`, `\firstH` is the first hour present on the timetable, in my case 8:00 am: `08.00`.

The command is used as this: `\calentry{1}{10.00}{10.45}{title}{location}{fillColor}{textColor}` where `1` defines the weekday (Monday), `10.00` the starting time of the appointment (10:00 am) and `10.45` the ending time of the appointment (10:45 am).

---

#### Full code of the project

Please see my [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/SamThilmany/99f0a18bef678279686bdf3c4900302a). Feel free to suggest improvements.

Comment: regarding to your reputation you should know, that is simpler to help you, if you instead of code snippet provide complete small document -- *mwe* -- which we can copy and test in our computers. also give a link is not appropriate. it can be discontinue after while and members after than can not see, what is the problem.

Comment: `minimum height=time(#3)-time(#2)`? Untested though.

Comment: `minimum height` doesn't apply to a multipart node. I propose (not tested): `\draw
        (#1, {time(#2)}) rectangle (#1+1, {time(#3)}) node [pos=.5, minimum height=time(#3)-time(#2), text width= \entrytextwidth cm, text centered, fill=#6]{\phantom{\small{\textbf{#4}}}\\\phantom{\footnotesize{#5}}}
        node [
            rectangle split, 
            rectangle split parts=2, 
            pos = .5, 
            text = #7, 
            text width = \entrytextwidth cm, 
            text centered
        ] 
        {\small{\textbf{#4}} \nodepart{second} \footnotesize{#5}};
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the `fit` library:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit} %% new library

%% some missing definitions
\def\entrytextwidth{2}
\def\firstH{0}

%% your new macro:
\newcommand{\entry}[7]{
    %% define the corners of the rectangle as coordinates:
    \path
        (#1, {time(#2)}) coordinate (A)
        (#1+1, {time(#3)}) coordinate (B)
        ;
    %% draw the rectangle:
    \draw (A) rectangle (B);
    %% draw the node:
    \node (fillcolor) [
            fit={(A) (B)}, %% fitting both coordinates
            inner sep = 0, %% do not take any more space than exactly fitting the height of the rectangle
            %rectangle split,
            %rectangle split parts=2,
            %pos = .5, %% not needed, as the node is not on the path anymore
            fill = #6,
            text width = \entrytextwidth cm,
        ] {};
    \node (title) at (fillcolor.center) [above]
        [text depth=0,text = #7,text centered]
        {\small{\textbf{#4}}};
    \node (location) at (fillcolor.center) [below]
        [text = #7,text centered]
        {\footnotesize{#5}};
    }

%% your function:
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{time}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\firstH-(floor(#1)+(#1-floor(#1))/0.6)}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [x=5cm,y=2cm] %% otherwise it seems to be too small
        \entry{1}{10.00}{10.45}{title}{location}{green}{red}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, this does not seem to work with the rectangle split, so two nodes separate nodes `(title)` and `(location)` are used for the text.

[image: result]

Note: since you didn't give an MWE, I just assumed some values.

Comment: This works pretty well, but the text is not exactly vertically centered. Do you know a workaround? `anchor = mid` doesn't do the job :/ PS: I updated the [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/SamThilmany/99f0a18bef678279686bdf3c4900302a) with the current code, so that you can see the misalignment.

Comment: I updated the answer to use two extra nodes for the title. With your github code this now looks better regarding to the centering.